# Syntax error log table in Redshift

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling, etl, amazon-redshift

I am writing a C# routine to run the ETL codes,loading the data from our staging tables to data warehouse. We have many pieces of SQL code to do the ETL for multiple tables. Rather than copying those long pieces of codes into C# routine, I want to run those whole SQL files in C# directly.

The concern here is than what if there are errors in one of those sql files, how I can trace the specific error? If I just copy the ETL code to C# routine, I can see the error in the C# log, but if I run the sql file, where I can refer the error to?

I check the STL Tables for Logging in Redshift schema, there is an error table for data loading, but it is just for COPY command against S3.

My question is, is there any system table in redshift to log the SQL error messages?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a error log table names stl_error and you can return the context column as your error message.
`select * from stl_error where userid=[YourUserId]`